# Group by and create a list without a given value (nan)

Tags: python

**Please note this is just an example, the real case is with very big lists**

Having:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Peter','Peter','Anna','Anna','Anna'],'Country':['Italy',np.nan,np.nan,'Sweden',np.nan],'Price':[12,33,45,6,9]})
```

I do

```py
data_g_name = data.groupby('Name')
g_stats = pd.DataFrame({
    'Countries':data_g_name.apply(lambda x:x['Country'].values.tolist()),
    'TotalCost' : data_g_name['Price'].sum()
})
```

And obtain:

```
     Name           Countries        TotalCost
0    Anna       [nan, Sweden, nan]     60
1    Peter      [Italy, nan]           45
```

I would like (without having to iterate through the list if possible):

```
     Name           Countries        TotalCost
0    Anna            [Sweden]          60
1    Peter           [Italy]           45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each "Name" has only one value for "Country", you can use `first` to aggregate the "Country" column:

```
>>> data.groupby("Name").agg({"Country": "first", "Price": "sum"})
      Country  Price
Name                
Anna   Sweden     60
Peter   Italy     45
```

If there could be multiply "Country" values, use:

```
>>> data.groupby("Name").agg({"Country": lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), "Price": "sum"})
        Country  Price
Name                  
Anna   [Sweden]     60
Peter   [Italy]     45
```